# How may i use pdf-form gem to create Pdf in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pdf-form

I am working on a project in Rails where i want one form in which user may enter any value he want like pdf form and after that when he submits the form pdf must be generated.I dont know how may i use pdf-form for that purpose.

Comment: You need to use wicked_pdf for pdf generation it is dead simple 
Go through it's documentation and if you find any difficulties implementing comment here.
https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

Comment: first: you changed database.yml setting for mysql ?
second: Try using this command to take dump from your environment mysqldump -h [host] -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql
this will generate a dump file which you will need to enter in your database;
Third: this is a diff question so you should have asked in another question.

Comment: where this dump fill will be located?????   mysqldump -h [host] -u [uname] -p[pass] db_name > db_backup.sql  and what we have to specify in -h [host]. Because i have the database.sql file generated only problem is  its not going in databse and there is no error.

Comment: That depends on you where the dump file will be.
if you are inside your app directory like ubuntu/home/your_app_name and firing the dump command from there then it wil be located in your app folder only.
and to import that dump file you need to log-in into your mysql
follow these steps:
1. mysql -u username -p password
2. show databases;
3. use your database_name;
4. source your dump_file_name;

Comment: Look i don't know much about windows as I've never worked with rails on windows but mysqldump -h [hostname means the host which is provided by your hosting service when you deployed your rails app] -u [uname means your username for mysql] -p[pass your password for mysql] db_name(the name of your database if you are on local then it should be generally your app_name_development) > db_backup.sql(this is the name of the file which will be generated)

Comment: if you dont mind will you please specy in step by step what i must do???????? i am new to mysql database.

Comment: i too not worked on windows

Comment: i have a database.sql file which was automatically generated,i that there are various insert comand for tables.That i need to run and copy all my records to tables.

Comment: there was one file which was generated while i ran rake db:load....database.sql ....in that there are various insert command....now you tell me....db_backup,sql is the file which is in db?? right........you mean to say....

Comment: then what is that file which was generated automatically while i ran rake db:load.....database.sql???????? what is the use of taht fie........????????????????

Comment: :/ I already told you how do you import that file into your database. what else do you need ?

Comment: done successfully bro,,,...thanks....will you upvote all my question...i want to increase my reputation.........

Comment: Ok i'm posting this as answer then you accept my answer and i will. :)

Comment: i am also from mumbai....?????

Comment: ok i will accept your answer...you have to upvote all my questions......!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139362/discussion-between-chirag-arya-and-mahesh-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use wicked_pdf for pdf generation it is dead simple Go through it's documentation and if you find any difficulties implementing comment here. [github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf](http://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf)

And to your second query you need
to import that dump file you need to log-in into your mysql follow these steps:

1. mysql -u username -p password
2. show databases;
3. use your database_name;
4. source your dump_file_name;